# Solve the triangle trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

Solve the triangle $PQR$ where.

$q=2.9\text{ m}$

$r = 3.5\text{ m}$

$\angle LQ = 25^{\circ}$

Does the $\overline{LQ}$ mean right angle triangle?

Should I use $3.5 \text{ m}$ as the hypotenuse?

Comment: I can't do the sign correctly, it isn't an L but it looks like that. I'm not sure how to use the illustration tools on the website.

Comment: Maybe what you intended was $\angle Q=25^\circ$. Then the triangle is not right-angled.

Comment: I'm editing your post but what are 'q' and 'r'? Shouldn't lengths be PR/PQ/etc.?

Comment: An alternate system is to use a lower-case letter to designate the side opposite the same letter angle;  Side a is opposite Angle A, Side b is opposite Angle B and so on...

Comment: Hi, thank you Andre and Shahar. I'm not used to seeing that either, I've normally encountered the same problems you stated. PR/PQ etc. Not r=/q=. I've got two sides and an angle but have no idea what to do with them.

Comment: I can work out the missing sides and angles If i know where this information goes, I'm not sure where to place the LQ or if to use 3.5m as the hypotenuse.

Comment: I doubt it's a right triangle. However, I have no idea what $q$ or $r$ are.

Comment: @user136213:  If standard notation is being used, then $q$ is the side or side length opposite vertex $Q$, and $r$ is opposite vertex $R$. so it is the trickiest of the standard problems. Use the Sine Law to first find the sine of $\angle R$.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not clear which angle is 25 deg. considering angle Q as 25 deg.
and given that PQ=3.5 & PR=2.9 hence sin(Q) = PR/PQ [as you want consider PQ as Hypotenuse hence angle R is 90 deg] for Right angle triangle but as you can see it is not same.
Also if we assume that somehow angle  P is 90 deg then tan(Q)=PR/PQ which is again not same. Hence this triangle can not be a right angle triangle.